# How to debug multiple scenes loading at the same time in unity?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We have a really weird bug in out game where when we upload it into Beta and send it out through test flight, so phones play the game as intended and other phones have a weird issue pictured below:

[image]

From the image you can see the problem.  One it does a ghosting type of thing with the characters as they move.  Two, it acts like no scene is actually closing, but keeps stacking them on top of each other.

This problem does not occur on iPhone 6s or iPad Pro.  It also doesn't occur on Android.  We have only seen it on 5S and iPads.

We have looked at versions and that doesn't seem to be an issue either.  We are using Unity 5.3 for this build (we reverted to this build as we felt it was the most stable, just to make sure that wasn;t an issue)

Anyone have an idea of what could be causing this problem?

Keep in mind that the things that are being seen are in different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

in your **camera settings** you probably set **clear flags** to **Dont clear** set it to **Depth only**

Comment: It was on Depth Only.

Comment: try setting it to a solid color